# Mongodb select nested document using condition and then update the same nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to select all subdocuments based on particular conditions and then update the same subdocumnets:

example:

i have following 2 documents

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "item" : "TBD",
    "stock" : 0,
    "info" : {
        "publisher" : "1111",
        "pages" : 430
    },
    "tags" : [ 
        "technology", 
        "computer"
    ],
    "ratings" : [ 
        {
            "by" : "ijk",
            "rating" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "by" : "lmn",
            "rating" : 5
        }
    ],
    "reorder" : false
}

{
    "_id" : 6,
    "item" : "TBD",
    "stock" : 0,
    "info" : {
        "publisher" : "1111",
        "pages" : 430
    },
    "tags" : [ 
        "technology", 
        "computer"
    ],
    "ratings" : [ 
        {
            "by" : "ijk",
            "rating" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "by" : "lmna",
            "rating" : 5
        }
    ],
    "reorder" : false
}
```

In this case i want to select subdocuments where rating is 5 and then update all such subdocuments with rating 9.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: let us know what query you have tried

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Use updateMany and positional operator [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update the matching index

```
db.collectionName.updateMany({'ratings.rating':5}, {$set: {'ratings.$.rating':9}})
```

As Alex mentioned in comment, the above query will just update the first matching element in the array. If you want to update all matching elements then you have to iterate and update each record

```
db.rate.find({'ratings.rating':5}).forEach(function(doc){
  var ratings = [];
  doc.ratings.forEach(function(r){
    if(r.rating == 5){
        r.rating = 9;
    }
    ratings.push(r);
  });
  db.rate.findOneAndUpdate({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {ratings: ratings}});
})
```

Comment: It updates **first** matched subdocumnet, not **all** subdocuments. Mongodb is a document db, not a subdocument one. There is no way to achieve what OP asks in a single query.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this??? and is there any other nosql db present with such ability?

Comment: Very good update. I'd only add a disclaimer that it works in the mongo shell only. The same technique can be applied in an application, but `forEach` loop needs to be implemented on the application level using specific language constructs.